# I want to change the display order of the billing address in the check-out process of Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

[image]

I've been using Drupal 9 and want to change the display order of the address section in images to the Japanese style. Despite searching extensively and trying different things, I still haven't figured out how to do it after more than six months. There's limited information available, and the system is complex and confusing. Can someone please show me how to change the display order of this part?

Comment: Interesting. This is supposed to be localized to a Japanese format by default. The commerceguys/addressing library appears to have the correct local format (can you confirm at https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing/blob/master/src/AddressFormat/AddressFormatRepository.php#L731), but perhaps Commerce isn't using the local format when rendering here?